# Find duplicate records in database against unique attributes

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

I want to find duplicate of IRN # entered into a table in database. Here are the unique attributes (logically unique) of the IRN.

```
ProjectNo, DrawingNo, DrawingRev, SpoolNo, WeldNo
```

An IRN can have multiple WeldNos meaning the above unique attributes may repeat for one IRN # (with of course one of the 5 attribute values must be unique).

Now I am trying to find out whether there are any duplicate IRNs entered into the system or not? How can I find that through a sql query?

P.S: Due to bad design of database, there is no primary key in the table..

Here is what I have tried so far but this does not give the correct results.

```
select * from WeldInfo a, WeldInfo b
where a.ProjectNo = b.ProjectNo and
a.DrawingNo = b.DrawingNo and
a.DrawingRev = b.DrawingRev and
a.SpoolNo = b.SpoolNo and
a.WeldNo = b.WeldNo and
a.IrnNo <> b.IrnNo;
```

Comment: You didn't define duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

But i'm not sure, have i  understood your question.

```
select  * from (
select count(*) over ( partition by ProjectNo, DrawingNo, DrawingRev, SpoolNo, WeldN) rr,t.* from WeldInfo t)
where rr > 1;
```

Explanation.

```
with tab as (
select 1 as id, 'a' as a , 'b' as b , 'c' as c from dual
union all
select 2 , 'a', 'b', 'c' from dual
union all
select 3 , 'x', 'b', 'c' from dual
union all
select 3 , 'x', 'b', 'c' from dual
union all
select 3 , 'x', 'd', 'c' from dual
)

select t.*
      , count(*) over (partition  by a,b,c) cnt1
      , count(distinct id) over (partition  by a,b,c) cnt2
from tab t;
```

Comment: I tried this but it says it has syntax error.'missing left parenthesis'

Comment: it certainly returned some data but I doubt the result is correct. Can you please explain what the above query does?

Comment: query returns only rows where set of columns( ProjectNo, DrawingNo, DrawingRev, SpoolNo, WeldN) aren't uniquere in dataset

Comment: you can also change count(*) to count(distinct IrnNo)